# React - Unexpected Identifier error in my App.js file. I don't understand why

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql, apollo

I'm following a tutorial on how to build an app using React, GraphQL, and Apolo. I've run into an Unexpected Identifier error when I start the app ("node App.js"). This error seems to be with "import React" and I don't understand why.

Also, I'm using concurrently to run front and back end with "npm run dev" and get a different error.

I've tried reinstalling the packages. I've started server.js and App.js separately. Server works fine but not App.js (as explained above).

This is the error:

```
_Tutorial_Follow-Alongs/GraphQL_React-Apollo_Tut_Follow/client/src/App.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import React, { Component } from 'react';
                                                                     ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at new Script (vm.js:73:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:245:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:297:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:266:19)
EFs-MacBook-Pro:src ef$
```

This is my App.js code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-boost';
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';
import Launches from "./components/Launches"
import "./App.css"; 
import logo from "./assets/images/logo.png";

// With Apollo wrap the component in a provider and pass in a client
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "http://localhose:5000/graphql" //path to the one endpoint created using graphql in server.js
});

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (

      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <div className="container">
        <img 
          src={logo}
          alt="SpaceX"
          style={{ width: 300, display: "block", margin: "auto" }}
        />
      </div>
      <Launches />
      </ApolloProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is the error when using conrcurently, "npm run dev"

```
Failed to compile.
[1] 
[1] ./node_modules/react-dev-utils/formatWebpackMessages.js
[1] Module not found: Can't resolve '/Users/ef/Documents/UCF CODING BOOTCAMP/UCF_Local/_PRACTICE/_Tutorial_Follow-Alongs/GraphQL_React-Apollo_Tut_Follow/client/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/slicedToArray' in '/Users/ef/Documents/UCF CODING BOOTCAMP/UCF_Local/_PRACTICE/_Tutorial_Follow-Alongs/GraphQL_React-Apollo_Tut_Follow/client/node_modules/react-dev-utils'
```

In both cases, the app won't run. I'm totally stuck. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Without more information its hard to say , to use the import syntax you'll need to 
 have your code transpiled using babel ,  if you are usig webpack could you post your .babelrc and webpack.config files please. Or give a link to the lesson github repo.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Here's my reop: https://github.com/efinfl/GraphQL_React-Apollo_Tut_Follow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

This problem is occurring because you are trying to execute frontend code meant for the browser with `node`.

This does not work as you can see with this example:

[image]

The code is meant to be *served* by your server and *executed* in a browser.

For the second error, it seems that you are using CRA in the `client` directory, which has it's own `package.json`. So you should just be able to `npm install --prefix client` from the root directory to install the dependencies in the `client` folder.

Comment: Thank you very much, Matty. My apologies for neglecting to change my repo to public. I have changed it if you wouldn't mind taking a look.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I missed the second error. Did you do an `npm install` in the client directory? I'll clone it and see if I can't debug what's going on.

Comment: I was able to get it running locally after running `npm install --prefix client` to install the dependencies specified in `client/package.json`

Comment: For some reason, reinstalling the dependencies didn't work on my existing local files. I had to clone my repo into a new local directory and installed the dependencies from the root directory (npm install, npm install --prefix client.) and that worked.  Thank you so much for taking the time to help me!

Comment: Great! Glad to help. Feel free to mark my answer as correct  I’ll update it with the npm install commands for future reference